# Toggle SlateJS editor's readonly props

Tags: slatejs

I am playing with [SlateJS](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate) `v0.34.5`. Is there any way to toggle Editor readonly state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out. So silly of me. adding `readOnly` property in `state` and then in `Editor` passing it as follows

```
<Editor readonly={this.state.readOnly} />
```

Then doing regular `setState` stuff for toggling it.